# RMagick - How to convert/overlay two images (same as command line `convert img1 img2`)

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I am trying to put a logo in top of an image, and I have this command that works as I want it to.

```
convert base.jpg logo.png -gravity southeast -geometry +10+10 -composite output.jpg
```

I can't figure out how to convert this into ruby/RMagick code. All the docs/SO posts show RMagick just taking one image arg, but I need to pass two. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/blob/develop/examples/crop_with_gravity.rb#L27

Answer (score 0):

Try the #composite method in Image.

https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#composite